# leaflet pixel size depending on zoom level

Tags: leaflet

I have to display 5x5 degrees pie chart on a leaflet map. I can display pie chart using the great [leaflet-dvf](https://github.com/humangeo/leaflet-dvf) library, but I have to provide the radius in pixel, and it is static so far.

I would like to have it dynamic so that at any zoom level, the pie chart fills the 5x5 square (aka radius = 5x5 degree length).

How can I know the length in pixel of the side of a 5x5 degrees square, depending on the zoom level?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This will work out metres per pixel

```
metresPerPixel = 40075016.686 * Math.abs(Math.cos(map.getCenter().lat / 180 * Math.PI)) / Math.pow(2, map.getZoom()+8);
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the following page that provides the pixel per meter on a leaflet map depending on the zoom level:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels

Then I computed the length of a 5x5 square at the equator: 556000 meters.
Then I store the length ratio for zoom level = 0: 
$scope.lengthRatio = 556000 / 156412 // in meter / pixel

Finally, I get the radius of a pie chart depending on the zoom level ($scope.mapZoom):

var radius = $scope.lengthRatio * Math.pow(2,$scope.mapZoom)) / 2

The /2 is because I want the radius and not the diameter

Simple!